# How to get an event to prompt to create a calendar event in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I sometimes receive email containing time and place for an event, and it automatically shows in my Google Calendar, or at least the time and place is a link format that I can click to add to my calendar.

Now I can't figure out how to send something like that. I tried simply typing

```
June 2, 6:30pm
```

in the text and Gmail doesn't recognize it.

How can I format the text so that Gmail recognizes it as a date and time and lets me create a calendar event?

Comment: Are you sending it to yourself? I've found that it doesn't work on messages where I'm the sender. I need to send the message from a different account.

Comment: Related: [Guidelines on email formatting to make contents Google Calendar friendly ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17828/354)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating the event in Google Calendars and sending the email from there?

So if you click on a time period in Google Calendars, and create an event you can invite people to this event from your email to their email. This should send them an invitation to the event.